# Почему иногда я получаю ошибку unlink file?

Tags: git

Не могу понять от чего зависит такое поведение гита, но иногда когда я делаю мердж между ветками вот так

```
git merge --no-ff dev_br
```

то вконце получаю вот такое

```
Counting objects: 65484, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (17088/17088), done.
Writing objects: 100% (65484/65484), done.
Total 65484 (delta 47220), reused 62922 (delta 45157)
Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack- 
00f739044dc3b505653d460395d8be74e3f1d48f.idx' failed. Should I try again? 
(y/n) n
Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack- 
032354f00b76ba52e14e8e025c1d6a8612b33df2.pack' failed. Should I try again? 
(y/n) n
Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack- 
032354f00b76ba52e14e8e025c1d6a8612b33df2.idx' failed. Should I try again? 
(y/n) n
Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack- 
066bec9d7ca881466e7e459983b1740d2f40dc10.idx' failed. Should I try again? 
(y/n) n
Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack- 
0d69d4aecaecb8e0a9db4d188f5a59665b59111a.pack' failed. Should I tnry again? 
(y/n)
Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack- 
0d69d4aecaecb8e0a9db4d188f5a59665b59111a.idx' nfailed. Should I try again? 
(y/n)
Unlink of file '.git/objects/pack/pack- 
0d7d3657f508080cfabc0dfceb7e893bdcafdd74.pack' failed. Shonuld I try again? 
(y/n)
```

только таких строк штук 100

2 вопроса

- почему это получается
- что делать? Потому что мне приходиться 100 раз нажимать `n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такие ошибки могут возникать, когда файл, с которым пытается оперировать  git, используется какой-то другой программой.
Потенциальных решений может быть несколько:

1. Можете попробовать позакрывать другие программы и попытаться понять, какая из них именно использует или делает вид, что использует файлы. Потециальные кандидаты - IDE, другие git клиенты (вполне может остаться "висящий" процесс от крэшнутой программы) или git, запущенный в другом экземпляре командной строки.
2. Судя по вашему логу, все файлы - не содержимое вашего проекта, а служебные файлы гита или какие-то временные файлы. Команда `git gc` может помочь. Эта команда удаляет временные файлы репозитория, подробнее [в документации](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc). Если команду запустить не получится (может выругаться на то, что эта программа уже запущена), попробуйте `git gc --force`
3. Если речь идет об ОС семейства Windows, у некоторых такая проблема возникает из-за того, что командная строка открывается с недостаточными правами. Можете попробовать запустить командную строку с админскими правами (Run As Administrator).
4. Еще проблема может быть в длинне пути к файлам, которая имеет ограничение на уровне ОС. Если проблема связана с этим, то `git config --global core.longpaths true` теоретически может помочь решить проблему. Это опять же случай более касающийся Windows, нежели других ОС (На практике был случай, когда один и тот же репозиторий без каких-либо проблем работал на MacOS и не давал сделать ни одной операции на Windows 10).

Comment: От куда вы все это знаете?) Мне кажется, что самое вероятное это то, что git используется другой программой, так как у мне всегда параллельно открыта `GitKraken` (в ней удобно просматривать гит историю комитов). А команды я пишу в консоле вот и получается, что 2 программы параллельно используют гит. Я так понимаю, что в моем случае если такое случается, нужно написать `git gc` это должно получить

Comment: книженция Pro Git, практика и гугление) Надеюсь помог с решением проблемы) git gc может помочь, но не факт, что вы не столкнетесь тутже с этой проблемой через некоторое время. Думаю удобней будет либо перейти к работе с одним клиентом, либо просто закрывать GitKraken перед коммитом/мержем